# HTML into svg changed style

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to make an svg like this using this code:

```html
<svg fill="none" viewBox="0 0 800 400" width="800" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <style>
        /** By default, use the local font and then fallback to web font. **/
        @font-face {
          font-family: 'Segoe UI Web (West European)';
          src: url('https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/assets/fonts/segoeui-westeuropean/segoeui-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/assets/fonts/segoeui-westeuropean/segoeui-regular.woff') format('woff');
          font-weight: 400;
          font-style: normal;
        }
        .hello {
          -webkit-background-clip: text;
          -webkit-text-fill-color: #fff;
          o-text-fill-color: #fff;
          -webkit-text-stroke: 0.09375rem #0d1b1e;
          -o-text-stroke: 0.09375rem #0d1b1e;
          color: #fff;
          letter-spacing: 6px;
          text-shadow: 3px 3px 0px #80ff9b;
        }

        /* For demo purpose only: background-color should match surrounding color for effect */
        body {
          font-family: 'Segoe UI Local', 'Segoe UI Web (West European)';
          font-size: 40px;
          //background-color: #f2cee6;
        }
            
        .dot {
          font-size: 200%;
          color: #80ff9b;
          margin-left: -20px;
        }

        </style>
        <h1><span class="hello">Hi</span> ! I'm Susana <span class="dot">.</span></h1>
    </div>
</foreignObject>
</svg>
```

And it currently looks like this, as a html:
[image]

But my svg looks like this (or like the code snippet, it is overall different in the different browsers). The font and the style are kinda different:
[image]

The svg is embeded in an online platform.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try moving the styles in the css and set the font family for the svg foreignObject

Comment: @enxaneta Thanks for the comment! And how could I set the font family for the svg foreignObject ?

Comment: svg foreignObject { font-family : _whatever_....  }